# Uncaught TypeError: bot.setMyCommands is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf

[almost all rest bot methods are work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpIJ8.png)

```
bot.setMyCommands([
    { command: '/start', description: 'start a dialogue with Jarvis' },
    { command: '/repeater', description: 'make Jarvis repeat every your message' }
])
```

When I'm trying to run and debug code that includes this part of code I get the error "**Uncaught TypeError: bot.setMyCommands is not a function**", but there is excactly this code in offical documentation of framework telegraf

Comment: You can throw off the code completely. Namely, what do you assign to the `bot` variable

Comment: The snippet you provided is not rly useful. All it shows is you trying to call `bot.setMyCommands()` with is apparently not a function. Can you show where you get the bot object from? and link the site you have the snippet from

Comment: 've pined a  picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to type 'bot.telegram.setMyCommands()' instead of 'bot.setMyCommands()'